# Show specific images if a number is written in a certain field

Tags: twig

I have recently started with twig. For an online shop i want to display certain images, if there is a number written in a specific field. 
This is my code so far:

```
{% if not myItemData.free1 is empty %}
    <img class="free1img" 
         src="/documents/gefahrenicons/{{ myItemData.free1 }}.gif"
{% endif %}
```

It works as long as there is only one number written into the field.
When i put 02 in the field, the frontend shows the image 02.gif from that chosen folder.

Can someone help me how i would load multiple images, when they are written in the field like this: 
02, 03, 04

In this case picture 02.gif, 03.gif and 04.gif should be shown. Right now it is trying to load one image with the name 02, 03, 04.gif

Greetings,
Malwin

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the filter [`split`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html)

```
{% if not myItemData.free1 is empty %}
    {% for image in myItemData.free1|split(',') %}
    <img class="free1img" src="/documents/gefahrenicons/{{ image|trim }}.gif" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/qrg8gq)

Comment: Hey DarkBee, thank you so much for your answer! in the second row you write "for image". In my case the filename is just meant. Are you sure it sould work? Im asking because i havent got it working yet.

Comment: OMG YOUR CODE WORKS! I was to stupid to paste it to the right part of the file. Thank you so much!